# Matricial solution - Matricial system

Tags: matrices

I face the following problem. The matrix A is an auxiliary matrix, B and D are known and I look for C. Is it possible to obtain $C$ by means of $B$ and $D$?

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
A^{-1} = B C^{-1} \\
A = D C^{-1}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I thank in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: $C = AB$ and $C = A^{-1}D$. What kind of matrices are these?

Comment: A, B, C and D are positive (symmetric) matrices.

Comment: Then $C = (DB^{-1})^{1/2}B$.

Comment: You mean "positive definite", right?

Comment: Right. Positive implies in symmetry, I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the equality $AC = D$ that you have. Then
$$
CA = C^TA^T = (AC)^T = D^T = D = AC.
$$
Hence, $A$ and $C$ commute. From $AC = D$ we then see that $D$ commutes with both $A$ and $C$. The first equation gives you a similar statement so that in fact all 4 matrices $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ mutually commute with each other. Hence, we can treat them as if they were positive numbers.

So, for example, $C = A^{-1}D = BC^{-1}D$, so $C^2 = BD$. Taking the square root gives
$$
C = B^{1/2}D^{1/2}.
$$